# In-APP Email and Navigation Bar collide with each other

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

This is the code I'm using to present the in-app email:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailer setSubject:@"Look at this Job I found!"];
    NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Look at this Job I found:\n%@ (%@)\nSalary Rage: %@-%@\n Located in %@.\n%@\n%@.\n", _positionTitleLabel.text, _organizationNameLabel.text,_minSalaryLabel.text,_maxSalaryLabel.text,_locationLabel.text,_startDateLabel.text,jobsy.url];
    [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
    [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This is the result/issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl8ka.png

Comment: Have you tried `[self.navigationController presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil]`?  Presenting it from the navigation controller instead of the nested view controller may be the solution.

Comment: Yes, I get the same results. By looking at the email controller coming up on the screen I'm pretty sure that the collision is already there before it gets to the navigation bar.